# Why does Xcode create endless folder recursion?

Tags: xcode, recursion, directory

I am new to Objective C, Xcode (4.3.2) and Mac OS (10.7.3). I have noticed that several of my Xcode projects have an endless folder recursion in the project folder. This is not visible in Xcode, only in Finder. Has anyone encountered this or know anything about it? When viewing the folder in Finder, it looks something like this:

```
- projectName
  file1.h
  file1.m
  file2.h
  file2.m
  - projectName
    file1.h
    file1.m
    - projectName
      file1.h
      file1.m
      ... and so on ...
```

Not all files in the top folder are in the subfolders, but all subfolders seem identical (although I never reached the end of this bottomless structure).

I cannot see any indications that these subfolders are for example aliases.

Comment: Encountered the same just for a couple of minutes. Anyone info on this? I deleted the recursive folders, project is fine.

Comment: Same here, deleted and no worries. XCode 4.3.2

Comment: This is a really dangerous bug. It can easily lead to Duplicate Symbol errors and if you don't know about the recursive folders they would be very hard to track down.

Comment: For the record, it's still an issue in Xcode 4.4

Comment: It just happened to me in Xcode 4.5.2.

Comment: Same here, XCode 4.6.1. My project of 40MB turned to 2.35GB. It took me time to figure out which of the subfolders to delete.

Comment: same problem any one found why this is happening ? I didn't add any folders to the project so the below answer doesn't help

Comment: If anyone sees any xcode warnings for missing files after recursively deleting these folders and are using git for code management, make sure you do a `git add .` `git commit -am "message"` after the deletion -- the warnings will disappear.

Answer (score 6):

it happened to me before. You have to be very careful when you add a file to your project. If by mistake you double-click on a folder, it will be added in your project. And if that folder happened to be your project root folder, it is added recursively. 
The nasty thing is that it looks like Xcode is not doing it, but it is working really hard in the background to add all the files, and then they magically pop up later while you're not looking.

Answer (score 0):

Happend to me also, in Xcode 7. You can fix it by deleting the recursive folder. I also had to go in **Xcode** to **Project** -> **Build Phases** -> **Copy Bundle Resources** and I had to remove the folder with the name of the project (remove it by selecting it and clicking the minus sign).
Clean and build and it should work again...