# Xcode created circular loop in project file list and git commits fail

Tags: xcode, git

I have regrouped some files and added some code in my project and now I cannot get the git repo working properly. Commit button's text is "commit 1237 files" and if I press it commit screen dismisses and there is no error but my changes are not reflected in the repository.

I have looked at the file/folder structure of the project it seems that xcode created a loop while managing the folders, there is a nesting folder with image and source files :

```
FolderA
    Some images
    Some source files
    FolderA
        Some images
        Some source files
        FolderA
            Some images
            Some source files
            FolderA
            ..so on
```

I have deleted the folder in the second lvl in finder and it looks ok there but still in the repo it shows more than 1200 files that needed to be committed. Is it possible to force a recheck in git or should I recreate a repo? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this post to know Why its happens [Why does Xcode create endless folder recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310700/why-does-xcode-create-endless-folder-recursion)

To solve:

```
1. Commit the code using Xcode.
2. Pull the code using Xcode
3. Delete the unwanted folder from finder.
4. Commit the code using Terminal
     $ cd <Git folder>
     $ git commit -a -m "Commit message"

5. Push the code using terminal
     $ git push <Remote_name e.g.: origin> <branch_name e.g.: master>
```

Comment: This relieved me of a huge headache! Thank you +1