# XCode won't let go of the previous source directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I use git for source control in my project, couple of days ago Xcode created an infinite folder loop in the project directory for that problem I have asked a question here [Xcode created circular loop in project file list and git commits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635614/xcode-created-circular-loop-in-project-file-list-and-git-commits-fail) but didn't get replies. The project directory looked like this:

```
ProjectRootFolder
    FolderA
        Some images
        Some source files
        FolderA
            Some images
            Some source files
            FolderA
                Some images
                Some source files
                FolderA
                ..so on
```

I decided to completely delete folderA and move its contents (some images and source files) to root folder. After doing that I reset the location of those images and source files to correct paths in the right pane, and Xcode is now able to locate them (file names are not in red, right clicking -> show in finder works)

But the `compile sources` and `copy bundle resources` in `build phases` still shows them under FolderA, ie.

```
AppDelegate.m ..in FolderA
```

and build fails with `clang: error: no such file or directory` for any of the files I moved from folderA to top level. I have deleted and re-added all of them but still Xcode thinks they are under FolderA. I have also tried deleting contents of DerivedData and cleaning build with cmd+opt+shift+K but no avail, the files seem to be cursed.

Is there any option besides creating a new project to fix the issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start again with a new Xcode project.

Comment: i feel like that's what I'll have to do, but it's worth to ask. otherwise i will lose my git repo, and all of the customizations I did that I don't even remember now.

Comment: I agree, however I don't think I could trust the project any longer if it caused errors like that.

Comment: Git should consider the project "file" replacement as a change, why would you lose the repo ? You can try to find the "FolderA" as text at the project files opened with a text editor (ctrl+click > show package contents), you'll probably find all the resources still being referenced there, then you could try to remove them. Do a backup first.